# How to prevent a single animated view from beeing recycled. RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm building a music-player-app and using a `RecyclerView`. When I choose a song from the list, the text(songname) starts scrolling horizontally. 
If I then scroll vertically, to look for other songs in the list, and then scroll back to the song that is playing, the horizontal scroll has stopped which is not desired.

When I press an item in the list I save that view in an instance-varible(for later use when changing song) and set `hasTransientState(true)`. 
The view that is scrolling horizontally(ScrollTextView) is custom made.
Method `playPauseStop` is called when an item is pressed.

To me it seems that onBindViewHolder in my adapater-class gets called even though I set `hasTransientState(true)` on a pressed view.

I managed to avoid this problem with a regular `ListView` using `setHasTransientState(true)` but
how can I avoid this problem using `RecyclerView`?
Any help is much appreciated.

```
public class TrackListFragment extends Fragment {

    private Context mContext;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private TrackAdapter mTrackAdapter;
    private IPlayer mPlayer;
    private int mCurrentTrack = -1;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mContext = context;
        mPlayer = new Player(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_layout, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    //mRecyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(0, 3);

        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        ArrayList<Track> tracks = null;
        if (bundle != null) {
             tracks = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("Tracks");
        }

         mTrackAdapter = new TrackAdapter(tracks, mContext);

         RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext);
         mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
         mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mTrackAdapter);

         mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(mContext, mRecyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.IClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            playPauseStop(view, position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

        }
    }));
    return view;
}

private ScrollTextView mStv;
private RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;

/**
 * mCurrentTrack is initially -1,
 * and set to -1 when media player is stopped.
 * @param position
 */
public void playPauseStop(View view, int position) {

    int firstViewItemIndex = ((LinearLayoutManager)mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
    int screenIndex = position - firstViewItemIndex;

    ScrollTextView stv = null;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)mRecyclerView.getChildAt(screenIndex);


    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        if(relativeLayout.getChildAt(i) instanceof ScrollTextView) {
            stv = (ScrollTextView) relativeLayout.getChildAt(i);
        }
    }

        if(mCurrentTrack == position && mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mPlayer.pause();
            stv.pauseScroll();
        } else if(mCurrentTrack == position && !mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            // Start after pause
            mPlayer.play();
            stv.resumeScroll();
        } else if(mCurrentTrack != position && mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            // Stop playing track
            mPlayer.stop();

            // Start new track
            mPlayer = new Player(mContext);
            String itemData = mTrackAdapter.getItem(position);
            mPlayer.startPlayThread(itemData);

            mStv.stopScrolling();
            mStv.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            mRelativeLayout.setHasTransientState(false);

            mStv = stv;

            stv.startScroll();
            stv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            relativeLayout.setHasTransientState(true);
            mRelativeLayout = relativeLayout;
            mCurrentTrack = position;
       }

       if(mCurrentTrack == -1) { // Initial. Start first track.
            mStv = stv;

            mCurrentTrack = position;
            String itemData = mTrackAdapter.getItem(position);
            mPlayer.startPlayThread(itemData);
            stv.startScroll();
            stv.setTextColor(Color.RED);

            relativeLayout.setHasTransientState(true);
            mRelativeLayout = relativeLayout;
            //mRelativeLayout.setHasTransientState(true);
        }
    }

}
```

My adapter:

```
public class TrackAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TrackAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private List<Track> mTracks;
private Context mContext;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView mTitle, mArtist;
        public ScrollTextView mScrollTextView;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
             super(view);
             mScrollTextView = (ScrollTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.scroll_track);
             mArtist = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.track_artist);
             mTitle =  (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.track_duration);
        }

    }

    public TrackAdapter(List<Track> tracks, Context context) {
         mContext = context;
         mTracks = tracks;
    }

    public String getItem(int position) {
          return mTracks.get(position).getLocation();
    }

    @Override
    public TrackAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
         View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.track_list_layout, parent, false);
         return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TrackAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
         Track track = mTracks.get(position);
         holder.mScrollTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
         holder.mScrollTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
         holder.mScrollTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         holder.mScrollTextView.setText(track.getTitle());
         holder.mArtist.setText(track.getArtist());
        //holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mTracks.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
         return i;
    }
}
```

XML RecyclerView:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
         android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
         android:scrollbars="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

XML Song Item View

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<package.name.custom.ScrollTextView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_track">

</package.name.custom.ScrollTextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/track_artist"
        android:layout_below="@id/scroll_track"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/track_duration"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```